# Dagger hilt missing binding issue. cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

I have started using dagger hilt. I have seen many tutorials and implemented basic sample. But i have discovered a issue that i have not being able to resolve. Although i have seen many questions on stackoverflow, but with no success. My code below,

Error log:

```
/Users/Shared/Previously Relocated Items/Security/Bitbucket_android/NotesAppApplication/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debug/com/abc/noteSample/api/NoteApplication_HiltComponents.java:132: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.abc.noteSample.api.NoteAPI cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements NoteApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.abc.noteSample.api.NoteAPI is injected at
          com.abc.noteSample.repository.NoteRepository(noteAPI)
      com.abc.noteSample.repository.NoteRepository is injected at
          com.abc.noteSample.ui.note.NoteViewModel(noteRepository)
      com.abc.noteSample.ui.note.NoteViewModel is injected at
          com.abc.noteSample.ui.note.NoteViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.abc.noteSample.api.NoteApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.abc.noteSample.api.NoteApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.abc.noteSample.api.NoteApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

Application class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class NoteApplication : Application() {
}
```

Interface

```
interface NoteAPI {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("GetPendingOrdersByManagerId")
    suspend fun getPendingOrders(@Field("AuthCode") AuthCode: String,
                                 @Field("ManagerId") ManagerLoginId: String,
                                 @Field("PageNumber") PageNumber: String) : Response<PendingResponse>
}
```

Network class

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesRetrofit() : Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesUserApi(retrofit : Retrofit) : UserApi {
        return retrofit.create(UserApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

Repository class

```
class NoteRepository @Inject constructor(private val noteAPI: NoteAPI) {

    private val _pendingLiveData = MutableLiveData<NetworkResult<PendingResponse>>()
    val pendingLiveData get() = _pendingLiveData

    suspend fun pendingOrders(pendingRequest: PendingRequest) {
        _pendingLiveData.postValue(NetworkResult.Loading())
        val response = noteAPI.getPendingOrders(pendingRequest.AuthCode,pendingRequest.ManagerId,pendingRequest.PageNumber)
        if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
            _pendingLiveData.postValue(NetworkResult.Success(response.body()!!))
        }
        else if (response.errorBody() != null) {
            val errorObj = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.charStream().readText())
            _pendingLiveData.postValue(NetworkResult.Error(errorObj.getString("message")))
        }
        else {
            _pendingLiveData.postValue(NetworkResult.Error("Something went wrong"))
        }
    }
}
```

View Model

```
@HiltViewModel
class NoteViewModel @Inject constructor(private val noteRepository: NoteRepository) : ViewModel(){

    val pendingLiveData get() = noteRepository.pendingLiveData

    fun getPendingOrders(pendingRequest: PendingRequest) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            noteRepository.pendingOrders(pendingRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

Calling Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding : FragmentMainBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val noteViewModel by viewModels<NoteViewModel>()

    private lateinit var adapter: NoteAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        adapter = NoteAdapter()

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        noteViewModel.getPendingOrders(PendingRequest("YWRtaW46MTIzNA==","19","1"))

       // binding.noteList.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
       // binding.noteList.adapter = adapter

        bindObserver()
    }
}
```

Kindly point out issue

Comment: You have provided you `UserApi` dependency in your `NetworkModule`. But did you also provide the `NoteAPI` dependency  somewhere?
Because the error is about the `NoteAPI` not provided.

Comment: @starball thanks for reply. i have solved the issue with Naresh NK guidance